# How does threejs attach a strip image material to a ring material？

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a strip map that I would ideally like to put into the torus map as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zXwJ.png)

Desired effect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs5AF.png)

But map configuration is linearly tiled by default, resulting in...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP5yc.png)

So how should I modify the uv map to get the desired effect?

Comment: Options: 1) [re-compute UVs](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/applying-a-texture-to-a-ringgeometry/9990/3), 2) [bend a plane](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-can-i-apply-png-as-a-2side-pattern-texure-on-a-ringbuffergeometry/43117/11) into a ring

Comment: Agreed.  You'll want a custom BufferGeometry in the shape of a circle, with `u` mapped around the radius and `v` mapped along it.